# Hiding nested anchors in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<a id="outer-anchor" href="/test">
    text in anchor
    <a id="inner-anchor" href="/test2" style="display:none"></a>
</a>
```

I tried this in different browsers and the inner-anchor drops out of the outer-anchor in every browser. So it gets rendered as this:

```
<a id="outer-anchor" href="/test">
    text in anchor
</a>            
<a id="inner-anchor" href="/test2" style="display:none"></a>
```

Does someone know why and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may/can not have an A in an A...

Comment: You have to move the node out of the parent anchor tag and add it after it. This is a JavaScript job.

Comment: <a> inside another <a> will render like that... not possible to render inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't house anchor tags inside anchor tags.

This would move the childNode out of the `outer-anchor` to be it's sibling after it, and then hide it nicely;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/TyGTL/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent-placeholder">
    <a id="outer-anchor" href="/test">
        text in anchor
        <a id="inner-anchor" href="/test2" style="display:none"></a>
    </a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer-anchor');
var inner = outer.nextSibling;

inner.style.display = 'none';

inner.parentNode.removeChild(inner);
outer.parentNode.appendChild(inner);
```

**Output**

```
<div id="parent-placeholder">
    <a id="outer-anchor" href="/test">text in anchor</a>
    <a id="inner-anchor" href="/test2" style="display: none;"></a>
</div>
```

`parent-placeholder` div purely exists to show how to relate to the parent DOM-element where the anchors are in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation!